# Returning functions inside closure returns undefined

Tags: javascript, function, module, return, closures

I've got an enclosed function in JavaScript like so:

```
var myFunction = function (options) {
    function blah() {
        var blahString = options.blahString;
        //more blah
    }

    function blah2() {
        //blah2
    }

    return {
        blah : function { return blah(); },
        blah2 : function { return blah2(); }
    }
};
```

When I'm in my HTML, I'm trying to call `myFunction.blah()` and it's telling me `the object has no method 'blah'`.

How do I access the returned functions in the global scope?

Thanks!

Comment: You either meant to have `var myFunction = (function (options) { })();` or call it like `myFunction().blah()`. I'm thinking you meant to have my first suggestion

Comment: If it's got arguments, is it okay to call `(function (options) { })();`?

I ask, because `myFunction(options)` supposed to be called in HTML, because this is a plugin.

Comment: Ahh I see. I didn't even consider `options`. So you probably want it the second way. You'd have to call it, like `var something = myFunction({a: 1, b: 2}); something.blah();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just explains why it doesn't work and how to make it work. For learning things this would be enough. Actually you should explain what you are trying to achieve so that others can guide you in the right direction.

```
// A scope of a function is activated ONLY when it is invoked

// Let us define a function
var myFunction = function (options) {
    function blah() {
        alert("I am blah");
    }

    function blah2() {
        //blah2
    }
    alert("I am active now and I am returning an object");
    return {
        blah: function () {
            return blah();
        },
        blah2: function () {
            return blah2();
        }
    };
};

myFunction.blah3 = function () {
    alert("I am blah3");
};

// myFunction is not invoked, but justed used as an identifier. 
// It doesn't have a method blah and gives error
myFunction.blah();

// blah3 is a static method of myFunction and can be accessed direclty using myFunction  
myFunction.blah3();

// myFunction is invoked, which returns an object
// it contains the function blah
myFunction().blah();

// or
var myObject = myFunction();
myObject.blah();
myObject.blah2();
```

Comment: Saving myFunction as an object makes it work - seems like it was a problem with my understanding of JavaScript objects. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
var myFunction = (function (options) {
  function blah() {
    return options.a;
  }

  function blah2() {
    //blah2
  }

  return {
    blah: function() { return blah(); },
    blah2: function() { return blah2(); }
  };
});

alert(myFunction({a:1, b:2}).blah());
```

This works fine. Note `blah: function` <-- needs `()`

see http://jsfiddle.net/kw6fJ/1

Comment: `myFunction(options)` isn't supposed to be called immediately, it's supposed to be called in HTML with a JSON object passed as `options`. 

If I include () at the end of the declaration, it gets called without any options and it errors out.

I'll edit the example so it requires the options variable.